# Asymptote : how to shift() * a pair[][]?

Tags: asymptote

I'm trying to make a (small) network graph in Asympote.  I don't want to use dot().
I draw unit circles and for each, I keep track of their cardinal points that I use as ports for edges.

```
size(10cm,5cm);
int strech =5;
pair vrtl = (0,2)*strech;
pair hrzl = (2,0)*strech;

path uc = unitcircle ;
pair ucp[] = {};  // unit circle ports
int k=4;
for (int i : sequence(k)) { ucp.push(relpoint(uc,i/k));};  

pair c1p[] = shift(vrtl)*ucp;  // ports for a circle above the uc
pair c2p[] = shift(vrtl*2)*ucp;  // ports for a circle above the previous one
pair Xp[][] = {ucp, c1p, c2p};  // packing 
Xp.append(shift(hrzl)*Xp);  // <- this is where I have a compilation problem
```

I was thinking of overriding the shift()* operator but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, the error message says:

```
op.asy: 14.22: no matching function 'operator *(transform, pair[][])'
```

so, you can just add the function

```
pair[][] operator *(transform tr, pair[][] a){
    return map(new pair[](pair[] p){return tr*p;},a);
}
```

then all `transform` operations (like `shift`, `rotate` or any custom transformation)
will work with `pair[][]` arguments as usual.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `shift` cannot take `pair[][]` as argument.
You can make by yourself such a function. Using `map` routine
a possible code is

```
pair[] sh( pair[] a)
 {
 return shift(hrzl)*a;
 }
map (sh, Xp);
Xp.append(map(sh,Xp));
```

or in a compact way

```
Xp.append(map(new pair[] (pair[] a ){return shift(hrzl)*a;},Xp));
```

O.G.